# Changing href attributes with nokogiri and ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parsing, string, nokogiri

I Have a HTML document with links links, for exemple:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="http://someurl.com/etc/etc">teste1</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://someurl.com/etc/etc">teste2</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://someurl.com/etc/etc">teste3</a></li>
   <ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want with Ruby on Rails, with nokogiri or some other method, to have a final doc like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://myproxy.com/?url=http://someurl.com/etc/etc">teste1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://myproxy.com/?url=http://someurl.com/etc/etc">teste2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://myproxy.com/?url=http://someurl.com/etc/etc">teste3</a></li>
    <ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

What's the best strategy to achieve this?

Comment: Are you dynamically building the html page in a rails template (ie .html.erb) or has it already been built and you want to re-scan it (using Nokogiri etc) after the fact?

Comment: The document is already built.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you choose to use Nokogiri, I think this should work:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'rubygems' rescue nil
require 'nokogiri'

file_path = "your_page.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(file_path))
doc.css("a").each do |link|
  link.attributes["href"].value = "http://myproxy.com/?url=#{CGI.escape link.attributes["href"].value}"
end
doc.write_to(open(file_path, 'w'))
```

If I'm not mistaken rails loads REXML up by default, depending on what you're trying to do you could use this also.

Comment: `link['href']` is a shortcut for `link.attributes["href"].value`

Comment: what if I want to output the changed to a variable ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did for replacing images src attributes:

```
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
       doc.xpath("//img").each do |img|
         img.attributes["src"].value = Absolute_asset_path(img.attributes["src"].value)
      end
      doc.to_html                  // simply use .to_html to re-convert to html
```