# Replacing link with additional information, how to exclude <img src="http://" tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm working on forum posts, where I need to replace user submitted url's with special formatting (including icon, etc). The user input could be following:

```
<p>This is a link: http://www.url1.com/</p>
<p>http://www.url2.com/</p>
<p><img src="http://www.url3.com/image.jpg"> something</p>
```

Specifically, I'd need to replace the two first links (url1.com & url2.com) with modified data (needs to be modified inside a code block, ~30 rows of code). However, I've yet to find a good way to implement such a thing.

If I do

```
html.gsub(/http[s]?:\/\/[^(\s|<)]+/) { |url| "REPLACED" }
```

I get:

```
<p>This is a link: REPLACED</p>
<p>REPLACED</p>
<p><img src="REPLACED something</p>
```

So basically, everything else except works, but img src is incorrectly detected as a link.

I also tried to exclude the possible starting characters for a link (" and ', as the html is sanitized beforehand, being valid html).

```
comment.gsub(/[^\"\']http[s]?:\/\/[^(\s|<\"\')]+/) { |url| "REPLACED" }
```

This kind of works, producing the following result:

```
<p>This is a link:REPLACED</p>
<pREPLACED</p>
<p><img src="http://www.url3.com/image.jpg"> something</p>
```

However, the first (and possibly last) character is lost. I tried to use \1, etc inside the code block, but couldn't find a way to include the first character.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the below code, and I am sure you get the desired output :

```
require 'uri'
text = '<p>This is a link: http://www.url1.com/</p>
<p>http://www.url2.com/</p>
<p><img src="http://www.url3.com/image.jpg"> something</p>'
URI.extract(text)
```

links => ["link:", "http://www.url1.com/", "http://www.url2.com/", "http://www.url3.com/image.jpg"]

And then replace all the links with the 'REPLACED' using gsub .

```
links.shift => "link :"
links.each do |link|
  text = text.gusb(link, "REPLACED")
end
```

and output of text is

```
"<p>This is a link : REPLACED</p>\n<p>REPLACED</p>\n<p><img src=\"REPLACED\"> something</p>"
```

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to avoid regex for HTML/XML bashing. Try nokogiri. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/610653/158285

**[UPDATE]**

or

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699994/158285

**[UPDATE]**

I've reworked the above to your problem and here it is

```
require 'cgi'
require 'rubygems' rescue nil
require 'nokogiri'

file_path = "your_page.html"
txt =  <<-EOF
    <p>This is a link: http://www.url1.com/</p>
    <p>http://www.url2.com/</p>
    <p><img src="http://www.url3.com/image.jpg"> something</p>
EOF
doc = Nokogiri::HTML txt
doc.css("img").each do |link|
  puts link
  link.attributes["src"].value = "REPLACED"
end

puts doc.to_s

# SECOND SOLUTION

require 'uri'
rtxt = txt.gsub URI.regexp do |match|
  "REPLACED"
end
puts rtxt
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I did not find a way to parse plain text urls (without a tag) in a nokogiri.

Comment: I don't understand. The example you posted has lots of html in it, ie **tags**. If you have the URL without the tags then just use http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-split to break the URI into pieces and reassemble it as you need

Comment: I've also added another stackoverflow question that shows you exactly how to do what you want.

Comment: Added a full solution that I tested in my shell for you :)

Comment: Updated the answer again to use the URL.regexp function which returns a regexp for a URI. You can then use that with gsub to replace all URI's.

Comment: And you should print out what URI.regexp returns. You will **never** **ever** try to roll your own URI regexp again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using rinku (https://github.com/tanoku/rinku/tree/)

```
Rinku.auto_link(comment, :urls, 'target="_blank" rel="nofollow"') do |url|
  "parsed stuff"
end
```